# Ocaml Exceptions With Try Catch

Tags: ocaml

I need to create a function that generates an exception in certain cases but I need it to generate a certain error using `try` `catch`. It uses functions :

```
let lookup (x,evn) =  match listAssoc(x,evn) with
|Some Int v ->Int v
| None -> raise (MLFailure "variable not found")
;;

let arithmetic (x,y,z) = match (x,y,z) with 
| (Int a, Int b, Plus)-> Int (a+b)
| (Int a, Int b,Minus) -> Int (a-b)
| (Int a, Int b, Mul)-> Int (a*b)
| (Int a, Int b, Div)-> Int (a/b)
;;
```

This is the function:

```
let errorlookup (x,evn) = match listAssoc(x,evn) with
| Some Int v ->Int v
| None -> raise (Nano.MLFailure "variable not found %s" x)
;;
let rec eval (evn,e) = match e with
| Const a -> Int a
| Var x-> (lookup (x,evn) )
| Bin( expr1, Plus, expr2) ->   arithmetic(eval(evn,expr1),eval(evn,expr2),Plus)
|Bin( expr1, Minus,expr2) ->  arithmetic(eval(evn,expr1),eval(evn,expr2),Minus)
|Bin( expr1, Mul, expr2) ->   arithmetic(eval(evn,expr1),eval(evn,expr2),Mul)
| Bin( expr1, Div, expr2) ->  arithmetic(eval(evn,expr1),eval(evn,expr2),Div)

;;
```

I need to make sure that in the `Var x` case, when `lookup` result is `None` I need to print an `Exception`

```
# eval (evn, Var "p");;
Exception: MLFailure "variable not bound: p".
```

`eval` evaluates an expression with a current environment, for example

```
let evn = [("z1",Int 0);("x",Int 1);("y",Int 2);("z",Int 3);("z1",Int 4)];;
val evn : (string * Nano.value) list =
  [("z1", Int 0); ("x", Int 1); ("y", Int 2); ("z", Int 3); ("z1", Int 4)]
```

I made the types for `Bin` and `Val` and `Expr` but those arent relevant to this.

I need to raise an exception based on the result of lookup but not raise the exception that is in lookup.  Someone suggested using `try` `catch` but I'm not sure how that would work for OCaml and this. This was the hint given by TA:

> `lookup` should throw the following exception:
>
> ```
> raise (MLFailure "not found")
> ```
>
> Whereas `eval` should throw the following one:
>
> ```
> # eval (evn, Var "p");;
> Exception: MLFailure "variable not bound: p".
> ```
>
> It seems that you've to do exception handling here. You can use the
>
> ```
> try <expression> with
> | <exception> -> <handler>
> ```
>
> syntax to catch & handle exceptions inside `eval`.

Comment: What is the question? Have you tried Google or the OCaml manual?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you're asking. But I suspect your TA has told you what you need to know. You can read about the OCaml `try ... with` expression in [Section 6.7](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) of the OCaml manual. This is the OCaml equivalent to `try ... catch` of some other languages.

If you want to catch a particular exception but let others propagate as usual, you just need to match the one you're interested in:

```
try
    <expression1>
with Not_found -> <expression2>
```

If you have complicated requirements, you can match several different exceptions, and after the match you can compute values and/or re-raise exceptions.

```
try
    <expression1>
with
| Not_found -> raise (MLFailure "abc")
| Divide_by_zero -> max_int
| _ -> raise (Invalid_argument "def")
```

Comment: can you give me an example of a match function and an exception on one of its matches, because I still think Im getting the format wrong.

Comment: i tried this and that doesnt work let lookup (x,evn) =   try match listAssoc(x,evn) with
|Some Int v ->Int v
| None ->raise(MLFailure "not found ")
;;

Comment: This code has syntax errors. You have one `match` and one `try` but only one `with`. There has to be a `with` for each `match` and each `try`. It also needs parentheses: `Some (Int v)`. I don't see a problem with the exception handling however.